# React warning - useEffect has a missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is my component:

```
const FooComponent = () => {
    const initFoo = {
        attrOne: '',
        attrTwo: '',
        attrThree: '',
    };
    const fooContext = useContext(FooContext);
    const { addFoo, hasFoo, currentFoo } = fooContext;
    const [foo, setFoo] = useState(initFoo);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (hasFoo) {
            setFoo(currentFoo);
        } else {
            setFoo(initFoo);    
        }
    }, [fooContext, currentFoo]);

    ...
    ....
}
```

I'm seeing the following warning in the console

```
Line 21:8:  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'initFoo'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Adding `initFoo` in the array `[fooContext, currentFoo]` that is passed in useEffect gives me further warnings and doesn't seem to fix the previous one. Both fooContext and currentFoo are required as inputs in the array as the functionality in the useEffect hook needs to be triggered whenever one of these two change a value.

```
Line 5:11:  The 'initFoo' object makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 21) change on every render. To fix this, wrap the initialization of 'initFoo' in its own useMemo() Hook  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? I've tried to search for similar cases this warning pops, but haven't found a similar example in here

Comment: Inline `initFoo` into the `useState` call, or move it outside of the component

Comment: Moved it outside of the component, the warning is gone, thanks! By the 1st option what exactly do you mean? not sure I understand

Comment: `const [foo, setFoo] = useState({attrOne: '', attrTwo: '', attrThree: ''});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component definition, every time it re-renders, you're re-creating the variable `initFoo`.

React hook linting isn't smart enough to figure out this case. It says "hey, I see you're creating a new object every time your component renders. However, you don't update your `useEffect` callback, which only is set once. So if your `initFoo` changes without your `useEffect` changing, then your `useEffect` could end up setting an old value of `initFoo`, causing bugs."

In your case, `initFoo` is the "same" every time. Moving `initFoo` outside of the component definition stops it from being re-created on every component render, so React hook linting sees that it can never change, so the `useEffect` callback could never become "stale" based on the value of `initFoo` changing.

Another option is to inline the use of `initFoo`:

```
useState({ attrOne: '', ... });
```

Which may be inconvenient here if you need to duplicate the result in `useEffect`.

This is also a warning, not an error, which you can ignore if you prefer to keep the declaration inside the component body for some reason. You can disable any ESLint rule with comments, if you want to ignore this warning, put this line above your `useEffect` call:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
```